# Qual o conceito e como implementar um Modelo de Domínio Anêmico?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

Gostaria de resolver as seguintes dúvidas acerca do Modelo Anêmico:

1. O que é o **Modelo de Domínio Anêmico**?
2. Quais são a diferenças de **implementação** desse modelo em comparação com o **Modelo Orientado a Objeto**? Se possível, apresentar um pequeno exemplo dos dois modelos na linguagem java.

Comment: Se não me engano, no outro dia fizes-te uma questão igual/semelhante, onde acabas-te por fechar... Apesar de ser uma questão pertinente, já tens alguma ideia sobre o Modelo Anêmico? Ou é trabalho de casa?

Comment: @CesarMiguel eu abrir esse post para ser uma via de pesquisa para outras pessoas e tenho uma noção com orientação à objetos, mas não com esse modelo. E só pelo fato de meus questionamentos a cerca desse assunto serem pertinentes não se trata de um "trabalho de casa", são duvidas próprias de minha autoria.

Comment: A quem votou pra fechar pela pergunta não estar clara: acho que você é que não entendeu a pergunta.

Comment: O termo completo é **Modelo de Domínio Anêmico** ou **Modelo Anêmico de Domínio**. É um assunto controverso. Eu pessoalmente acho que é um anti-pattern. Se ninguém mais responder, mais tarde de casa eu faço uma resposta.

Comment: @Renan blz.. se você postar a sua resposta ajuda muito^^ vlw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### O que é o Modelo de Domínio Anêmico?

O "Modelo de Domínio Anêmico", do inglês **Anemic Domain Model**, é um *design pattern* de desenvolvimento de software baseado no domínio do negócio (*domain*), onde objetos que representam modelagem do negócio (*model*) são "anêmicos", ou seja: desprovidos de comportamento.

Neste pattern, os objetos do model apenas carregam os dados, e os comportamentos de negócio são expostos por outras classes que recebem estes objetos anêmicos para processá-los.

### Quais são as diferenças de implementação desse modelo em comparação com o Modelo Orientado a Objeto?

A reposta para esta pergunta pode ser controversa. Alguns podem dizer que não se pode descrever diferenças pois o design pattern Anemic Domain Model também é orientado a objetos.

A noção de diferença nasce quando você aceita a proposição de que, na orientação a objetos, um objeto expõe **dados e comportamentos**. Neste caso, esta é a diferença: o design pattern Anemic Domain Model propõe justamente que estas coisas sejam separadas em objetos distintos.

### Um pequeno exemplo dos dois modelos na linguagem java:

#### Anemic Domain Model:

```
class ContaaPagar {

    double valorDevido;
    boolean pago;
}

class BaixaContaaPagar {

    void baixar(ContaaPagar contaaPagar) {
        contaaPagar.pago = true;
        contaaPagar.valorDevido = 0d;
    }
}
```

#### Outro design pattern (DDD, por exemplo):

```
class ContaaPagar {

    double valorDevido;
    boolean pago;

    void baixar() {
        // baixa esta conta a pagar
        pago = true;
        valorDevido = 0d;
    }
}
```

Comment: se uma classe tive apenas os atributos, get e setters e considerado anêmica?

Comment: @PedroRangel Não. Como você vai chamá-la depende da função dela e de muitas questões de acordo com as decisões de design do seu sistema.

Answer (score -1):

Com relação a esse ponto, imagine que você tenha pedidos que precisam passar por etapas. Teríamos uma classe Pedido, PedidoEtapa1, PedidoEtapa2 (essas duas herdando de Pedido), para executar a etapa 2 eu preciso que a etapa 1 esteja concluída. Se eu adotar o DDD, como eu resolveria a regra de negócio? A entity da PedidoEtapa2 faria acesso ao repositório da PedidoEtapa1?

```
class Pedido {
   int id;
   int numero;
   Date dataPedido;
}

class PedidoEtapa1 extends Pedido {
   Date dataEtapa1;
}

class PedidoEtapa2 extends Pedido {
   Date dataEtapa2;

   public Boolean etapa1Concluida() {
      ...
      return ?;
   }

}
```

Comment: isto me parece mais uma pergunta do que resposta, na próxima vez, use comentários ou faça a sua própria pergunta! :)