Modelos anêmicos vs. modelos ricos: quando usar?
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e me deparei com duas abordagens para organizar minha lógica de negócio, parece ser consenso que regras da aplicação devem ser tratadas em camadas superiores, então não acho que elas cabem nesse contexto.
No caso dos Rich Models, estado e comportamento são encapsulados juntos nas entidades, algo que parece estar bem alinhado com a orientação a objetos tradicional. No entanto, à medida que o sistema cresce, surge a dúvida: essas entidades não acabam acumulando responsabilidades demais? Como lidar com comportamento que precisa ser compartilhado entre várias entidades? Acredito que isso pode levar à criação de hierarquias de herança complexas ou até à duplicação de código para manter a coesão. Também fico pensando se esse modelo não acaba gerando muito boilerplate conforme as abstrações aumentam.
Por outro lado, os Anemic Models separam o estado das entidades da lógica de negócio, que fica centralizada em serviços específicos. Embora essa abordagem possa parecer "procedural", já que a lógica não está nas entidades, já vi definições de orientação a objetos que exigem o encapsulamento de estado e comportamento, mas também encontrei abordagens que não veem isso como uma regra absoluta. Fico com a dúvida se essa separação não acabaria ajudando na composição de serviços e na reutilização de lógica entre diferentes partes do sistema.
Além disso, percebo que com a abordagem Anemic + Services, os testes poderiam ficar mais fáceis, já que as responsabilidades estão bem separadas. Isso também me parece favorecer a composição de serviços e operações em lote (batch), onde a lógica de negócio não precisaria estar espalhada por várias entidades.
Já ouvi também o argumento de que, se o serviço é específico e lida somente com regras de negócio, então o modelo não seria realmente anêmico. Nesse caso, o modelo seria a combinação da classe entidade com a classe serviço, formando uma unidade completa de estado e comportamento, o que me deixa ainda mais em dúvida sobre essa distinção.
Observações

Quando falo de Rich Models, não estou me referindo ao padrão Active Record.

Quando falo de Anemic Models e Services, não estou sugerindo um Big Ball of Mud, onde os serviços acabam acessando e fazendo tudo. Pelo menos, acho que não estou indo por esse caminho.


No fim, em que situações faria mais sentido optar por Rich Models ou Anemic Models com serviços? Como lidar com as desvantagens de cada abordagem à medida que o sistema cresce?

Relacionados https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36966/137387 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310853/137387

Olá, ótimo! Já tinha visto essas, considerei elas enquanto escrevia a pergunta
